Update Non-Pixel Tablet to Android 15
This is a ODEA tablet currently running Android 14. I want to get to 15 to mimic my pixel phone. Any idea which factory or OTA image I can use?

The one ODEA puts out, if they ever do... Android on phones and tablets is not like Windows or Linux, it isn't "generic" in any sense... the ROM image needs to be specifically built for that device and digitally signed by the manufacturer to be loaded. You can't just take Android from device A and put it into device B, it won't work.

Here is where you can download new firmware if it ever gets released (unlikely).

Understood, and what I thought. Thanks both for your answers. I'll keep an eye on the ODEA site...though as you say, highly unlikely they will release an A15 build.
